# using nine patch images to draw to a canvas in android studio

Tags: java, android, canvas, nine-patch

I am currently using `canvas.drawCircle()` method to draw dots that represent objects on my screen.  I am having trouble using nine patch images instead of circles.  Could someone provide an example on how I can implement this?

```
public class SnakeView extends View {
private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
private TileType snakeViewMap[][];

public SnakeView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setSnakeViewMap(TileType[][] map) { this.snakeViewMap = map; }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(snakeViewMap != null) {
        float tileSizeX = canvas.getWidth() / snakeViewMap.length;
        float tileSizeY = canvas.getHeight() / snakeViewMap[0].length;

        float circleSize = Math.min(tileSizeX, tileSizeY) / 2;

        for (int x = 0; x < snakeViewMap.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <snakeViewMap[x].length; y++) {
                switch (snakeViewMap[x][y]) {

                    case Nothing:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        break;
                    case Wall:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    case SnakeHead:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                    case SnakeTail:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case Apple:
                        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                }

                canvas.drawCircle(x * tileSizeX + tileSizeX / 2f + circleSize / 2, y * tileSizeY + tileSizeY /2f + circleSize / 2, circleSize, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Specify what is exactly your problem, I am having a problem with it won't give much idea.

Comment: How could I use an image to implement the apple instead of just a red circle?  I am confused between a picture, bitmap and ninepatch

Comment: You can directly drawBitmap on to canvas

Comment: how can u draw a good apple by nine patch?? did u ever see stretched apple??

a simple bitmap could be use 
nine patch is also solution but that will stretched vertically or horizontally

Comment: So what is a better alternative, can I use a sprite?